# Trying to print the items in a list during a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to write a program for the people I am connecting with. What I'm trying to do in the for loop is to print the variable that is being passed through the loop along with the variable value. For some reason, when I do "print str(item)" in the first loop for the individual variables, nothing is printed for that. The "unknown" prints, but not the variable name.

On the other for loop, when I try to run the list name as a string, I get an error message saying "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects". How can I go about getting around this?

If it is not clear, what I am trying to do is print the variable name along with the value

```
List= [Name, Company, Email, Work, Cell, Address]
Name = "Last, First"
Company = ""
Email = ""
Work = ""
Cell = ""
Address = ""
Todo = ['Do this']
Done = ['Did this']
Follow = ['Follow up on this day']

for item in List:
    if item == "":
        print str(item)+ "unknown"
    else:
        print item



print " "

for item in List1:
    if len(item) == 0:
        pass
    else:
        print str(item) + item
```

Comment: I think you don't use an appropriate collection for your data. You want to stock values indexed by keys. So use a dict instead.

Comment: If the you had the  the variables after List in the code then you would  get `NameError: name 'Name' is not defined` so you would not even get as far as the loop. What is in List1?

Answer (score 0):

You need to move:

```
List= [Name, Company, Email, Work, Cell, Address]
```

Below:

```
Name = "Last, First"
Company = ""
Email = ""
Work = ""
Cell = ""
Address = ""
Todo = ['Do this']
Done = ['Did this']
Follow = ['Follow up on this day']
```

Otherwise it doesn't know what those variable types are. As for trying to print out what names the variables hold; that's a bit more complicated. This is because when going through the for loop they assume the name "item" in that scope. So even if you were to use the inspect module to get the name of the variable you will just end up having all the variable names being item. What you probably want to use is a Dictionary instead (OrderedDict if you care about order). It would look something like this:

```
List = {"Name": Name, "Company": Company, "Email": Email, "Work": Work, "Cell": Cell, "Address": Address}
```

Then you can modify your loop like this:

```
for item in List:
    if List[item] == "":
        print item + " unknown"
    else:
        print item
```

Also as a general practice it is never a good idea to name your variables after what type they are. Avoid calling your variables things like List, Int, String, etc.. It's a bad practice and will only lead to confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Put `List` after `Follow`; you're defining the components after you've put them in the list